# Select XPath of a Button?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML Code I need to select the Element that is highlighted. If the menu is highlighted I would like to select the button in the menu not the menu! If the menu is playfield I would like to select that.

```
<menu id="apl" class="highlight" widgetid="apl">
<button id="navi" selectable="true" widgettype="button" widgetid="audio_radio_apl_navi">
<button id="audio" class="highlight" selectable="true" widgettype="button" widgetid="audio_radio_apl_audio">
<button id="tel" selectable="true" widgettype="button" widgetid="audio_radio_apl_tel">
<button id="video" selectable="true" widgettype="button" widgetid="audio_radio_apl_video">
<button id="system" selectable="true" widgettype="button" widgetid="audio_radio_apl_system">
<button id="net" selectable="true" widgettype="button" widgetid="audio_radio_apl_net">
</menu>
<menu id="plf" widgetid="plf">
<img src="img/plf_radio.png"/>
</menu>
```

My code so far is:

```
focusedElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'highlight')]"));
```

This gets me the highlighted menu but I need the button!
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please define what 'If the menu is playfield i would like to select that' means to you?

Comment: If I select a menu then the menu[@class,'highlight']. But i do not want to select the menu element. I want the highlighted button, which is a child of the highlighted menu. If the menu[@id,'plf'] then I want the menu, because it holds no button.

Answer (score 4):

try this one

```
focusedElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='highlight']"));
```

as simple as it can get or

```
Select selectBox = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//menu[@id='apl']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this XPath should work for the example you provided.

```
//menu[@class='highlight']//button[@class='highlight']
```

It will look for a `<menu>` with `class='highlight'` containing a `<button>` with `class='highlight'`

Comment: Something went wrong: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //*[contains(@class,'highlight')]]//button[@class='highlight'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

Comment: How did it not work? Do you get an exception or does it not match anything?

Comment: Something went wrong: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//menu[@class='highlight']//button[@class='highlight']"}

Comment: Besides that I noticed there is a different error elso where as well. Still can´t address the element though.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the highlighted element has its dom changed or not.
Sometimes it is triggered by javascript, and creates a new element, which is quite problematic to be tested.
Or as mentioned above Iframe :D

Answer (score 0):

You'll need conditional statements:
you should check to see if element `"//menu[@id='apl']/button[@class='highlight']"` exists, if it does, click on it, if not, then click on `"//menu[@id='plf']"`

Answer (score 0):

```
focusedElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//menu[@id='apl']/button[2]"));
```